# Passing parameters to a stored procedure with a sql task

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis

I'm trying to pass variables to the stored procedure i have set up, i have them mapped in the Parameter Mapping tab. I think i may have the syntax incorrectly but i cant find a solution.

```
    EXEC [dbo].[proc_GetQuarterlyEmailId] 
    @employeeNumber = ?, 
    @employeeFirstName = ?, 
    @employeeLastName = ?, 
    @employeeEmail = ?
```

The error i am getting is:

> Executing the query "EXEC [dbo].[proc_GetQuarterlyEmailId] @employeeNu..." failed with the following error: "Could not find stored procedure ''.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

If i remove the parameters from the stored procedure and remove the parameter mapping it runs perfectly fine, so i know it can find it. I am using a ADO.NET connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to execute SP without parameters listed:

```
EXEC proc_GetQuarterlyEmailId ?, ?, ?, ?
```

I always use the syntax like this... and never have had problems...

And if procedure returns some rows when parameters are supplied, then you have to change the property "Reslut Set" to tomenthing else than "None"...

---

Mapping of parameters differs on which conection type you are using.
If you are using OLE DB you have to use question marks for parameters, as I mentioned yesterday. And for mapping in "Parameter Name" column you have to use numbers 0, 1, 2, ...
I'm attaching sample pics for "Result Set" = "None", as I have a SP that does not return eny resultset.

[image: General Tab]
[image: Parameter Mapping Tab]

Check also this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i tried that and it still gives me the same error. The Result set is set to "Single row" because that is what i'm getting back when the SP works.

Comment: Are you using the "Execute SQL task" transformation? If so, could you add  screenshots of the "Parameter Mapping" and "Result Set" setup as these have both caused me issues in the past

Comment: Mapping of parameters differs on which conection type you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Also, BypassPrepare HAS to be FALSE or it will give confusing "parameters not set correctly" errors.  I habitually set it to TRUE.